# Windows Phone Microphone api. Unable to playback on Android

Tags: android, windows-phone

I'm in the process of creating an app in Windows Phone, which records audio from the Microphone and sends it to a cloud storage.

I can record and playback on WP fine, but I'm trying to convert the data to Base64 and attach it to a JSON object.

This is what I'm doing now

```
    jsonObject.Recording = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.toArray());
```

Where stream is

```
    private MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(); 

    void microphone_BufferReady(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Retrieve audio data
        microphone.GetData(buffer);            

        // Store the audio data in a stream
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
```

And buffer is

```
    buffer = new byte[microphone.GetSampleSizeInBytes(microphone.BufferDuration)];
```

On the Android side I am decoding the Base64 and creating a .MP4 file for playback.
This fails as I'm pretty sure there is encoding/format issues.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

UPDATE:

The WP records in PCM, sample rate 16000 Hz, sample size 16 bits, channels 1, Audio encoding PCM.

As far as I can see, Android supports this.

I'm decoding it on Android like this:

```
    byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(jsonObject.getRecording(), Base64.DEFAULT);

    String path = getCacheDir().toString() + "recording.wav";

    File file2 = new File(path);
                    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file2, false);
                    os.write(decoded);
                    os.close();
```

And playing it like this:

```
    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
    mPlayer.setDataSource(fileInputStream.getFD());
    mPlayer.prepare();
    mPlayer.start();
```

Comment: define fails. you shouldn't use base64 as you risk to run into memory issues

Comment: It's only few seconds, so memory shouldn't be an issue.

But what would you suggest instead?

Comment: i usually use binary only, and make sure of not having any encoding at any point.

Comment: where exactly does it fail ? if you convert the base 64 back to audio on the WP, does it work ? do you transmit some form of hash to check the file integrity upon decoding ?

Comment: possibly. you have a list of supported formats here : http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: I've updated my question with details about encoding.

As I can see Android should support the media.